# Scala Function Currying and call By name Functions, GenricTypes

Tags: scala, function, currying

I am bit new to scala curying and the call by name functions. I am facing difficulty in understanding the Syntax. What is the fllow of the function why there is need of returning the f(result) and what function is applied on it further.

```
def withScan[R](table: Table, scan: Scan)(f: (Seq[Result]) => R): R = {
    var resultScanner: ResultScanner = null

    try {
      resultScanner = table.getScanner(scan)
      val it: util.Iterator[Result] = resultScanner.iterator()
      val results: mutable.ArrayBuffer[Result] = ArrayBuffer()
      while (it.hasNext) {
        results += it.next()
      }
      f(results)
    } finally {
      if (resultScanner != null)
        resultScanner.close()
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at just the function signature

```
def withScan[R](table: Table, scan: Scan)(f: (Seq[Result]) => R): R
```

Firstly, ignore the fancy currying syntax for now as you can always rewrite a curried function into a normal function by putting all the parameters in one parameter list i.e.

```
def withScan[R](table: Table, scan: Scan, f: Seq[Result] => R): R
```

Secondly, notice the last parameter is a function on its own and we don't know what it does yet. `withScan` will take a function somebody gives it and use that function on something. We might be interested in why someone needs such a function. Since we need to deal with a lot of resources that need to be opened and closed properly such as File, DatabaseConnection, Socket,... we will then repeat ourselves with the code that closes the resources or even worse, forget to close the resources. Hence we want to factor the boring common code out to give you a convenient function: if you use `withScan` to access the table, we will somehow give you the `Result` so that you can work on that and also we will make sure to close the resources properly for you so that you can just focus on the interesting operation. This is call the "loan pattern"

Now let's go back to the currying syntax. Although currying has other interesting use cases, I believe the reason it is written in this style is in Scala, you can use curly braces block to pass the parameter to the function i.e. one can use the function above like this

```
withScan(myTable, myScan) { results =>
  //do whatever you want with the results
}
```

This looks just like a built in control flow like if-else or for loop!

Answer (score 0):

As I understand that properly this is function which take some `Table` (probably db table) and try to scna this tabel using argument `scan`. After you collect data using relevant `scanner` this method just map collected sequence to object of type `R`.
For such mapping it is used `f` function.

You can use this function:

```
val list: List[Result] = withScan(table, scanner)(results => results.toList)
```

Or

```
val list: List[Result] = withScan(table, scanner)(results => ObjectWhichKeepAllData(results))
```

IMHO, it is not very well written code, and also I feel that the better would be to do mapping thing outside of this function. Let client do the mapping (which BTW should be for every single result) and leave scanning only for that function.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a higher-order function: a function which takes another function as a parameter.

The function appears to do the following:
- opens the passed in table with the passed in scanner
- parses the table with an iterator, populating entries in a local ArrayBuffer 
- calls a function, passed in by the caller, on the sequence of entries that have been parsed.

The function parameter allows this function to be used to carry out any operation on the scanned information, depending on the function passed in.

The function prototype could equally have been declared:

```
def withScan[R](table: Table, scan: Scan, f: (Seq[Result]) => R): R = {
```

The function has been declared with two argument lists; this is an example of currying.  This is a benefit when calling the function, as it allows the method to be called with a clearer syntax.

Consider a function that might be passed into this function:

```
def getHighestValueEntry(results: Seq[Result]): R = {
```

Without currying, the function would be called like this:

```
withScan[R](table, scan, results => getHighestValueEntry(results))
```

With currying the function can be called in a manner that makes the function parameter stand out more clearly.  This is helped by the ability in Scala to use curly braces instead of parentheses to surround the arguments to a function, if you are only passing in one argument:

```
withScan(table, scan) { results => 
    getHighestValueEntry(results) }
```